Why is the tk.Entry Widget not shown?
Why does is the Entry Widget with yellow background not shown?
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
entryText1 = tk.Entry(root, bg='yellow')
entryText1.delete(0,tk.END)
entryText1.insert(0,'Enter Upper Threshold:')
entryText1.pack()

root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()

It exists and when i click on it, the yellow color is visible.
I am using a Mac with Python 3.12.4
I played around a bit and if i just add a button afterwards, the Entry is shown correctly.
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()
entryText1 = tk.Entry(root, bg='yellow', fg="red")
entryText1.delete(0,tk.END)
entryText1.insert(0,'Enter Upper Threshold:')
entryText1.pack()

button= tk.Button(root)
button.pack()

root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()


If you put the Entry inside a Frame with a defined width and height it works again.
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

input_frame= tk.Frame(root, width=200, height=200)
input_frame.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(input_frame, bg='yellow', fg="red")  # Width of entry widget
entry.delete(0,tk.END)
entry.insert(0, 'Enter Upper Threshold:')
entry.pack()  
root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()

If you create a Frame without specifying a height AND width, the Entry is not visible again.
So the real question is: Why is tkinter not consistent or what exactly am I missing.
Is there a way to make the Entry visible after packing it?

I tested all the codes you provided on windows desktop (windows 11, Python 3.13.0), everything works fine, I don't see any problem.

Try to reinstall Python downloaded from official website.
